# Generate DDL with Oracle Sql Developer to include Foreign keys

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, oracle-sqldeveloper

I Tried a few options to generate DDL from oracle database using SQL Developer and none of them fit the purpose.

The Quick DDL option results in DDL without Foreign Key constraints. I do like the format

The Edit on table results in DDL including storage and loggings which I cannot get rid of.

Just wondering anyone have better way of generating DDL using SQL Developer?

Thanks

Comment: dbms_metadata.get_ddl

Comment: @OldProgrammer that's what sqldev uses to gen DDL, outside of that quick ddl operation

Answer (score 4):

The Quick DDL doesn't use any sort of preferences, it does it by what we think is appropriate - which is totally subjective of course.

However, if you go to the SQL page for an object in the tree, the DDL will be generated following the preferences set in Preferences > Database > Export.

[image]

For version 4.2, you can also use the DDL command in the worksheet. And you can use SET DDL to turn off or on the type of DDL you want generated.

```
SET DDL PRETTY ON;
SET DDL CONSTRAINTS ON;
SET DDL REF_CONSTRAINTS ON;
SET DDL PARTITIONING ON;
SET DDL TABLESPACE OFF;
SET DDL SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES OFF;
SET DDL STORAGE OFF;

DDL EMPLOYEES

DDL Option CONSTRAINTS on
DDL Option REF_CONSTRAINTS on
DDL Option PARTITIONING on
DDL Option TABLESPACE off
DDL Option SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES off
DDL Option STORAGE off
DDL Option STORAGE off
  CREATE TABLE "HR"."EMPLOYEES" 
   (    "EMPLOYEE_ID" NUMBER(6,0), 
    "FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(20), 
    "LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(25) CONSTRAINT "EMP_LAST_NAME_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(25) CONSTRAINT "EMP_EMAIL_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PHONE_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(20), 
    "HIRE_DATE" DATE CONSTRAINT "EMP_HIRE_DATE_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "JOB_ID" VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT "EMP_JOB_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SALARY" NUMBER(8,2), 
    "COMMISSION_PCT" NUMBER(2,2), 
    "MANAGER_ID" NUMBER(6,0), 
    "DEPARTMENT_ID" NUMBER(4,0), 
     CONSTRAINT "EMP_SALARY_MIN" CHECK (salary > 0) ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "EMP_EMAIL_UK" UNIQUE ("EMAIL")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "EMP_EMP_ID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("EMPLOYEE_ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "EMP_DEPT_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("DEPARTMENT_ID")
      REFERENCES "HR"."DEPARTMENTS" ("DEPARTMENT_ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "EMP_JOB_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("JOB_ID")
      REFERENCES "HR"."JOBS" ("JOB_ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "EMP_MANAGER_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("MANAGER_ID")
      REFERENCES "HR"."EMPLOYEES" ("EMPLOYEE_ID") ENABLE
   ) ;
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "HR"."EMPLOYEES"."EMPLOYEE_ID" IS 'Primary key of employees table.';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "HR"."EMPLOYEES"."FIRST_NAME" IS 'First name of the employee. A not null column.';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "HR"."EMPLOYEES"."LAST_NAME" IS 'Last name of the employee. A not null column.';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "HR"."EMPLOYEES"."EMAIL" IS 'Email id of the employee';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "HR"."EMPLOYEES"."PHONE_NUMBER" IS 'Phone number of the employee; includes country code and area code';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "HR"."EMPLOYEES"."HIRE_DATE" IS 'Date when the employee started on this job. A not null column.';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "HR"."EMPLOYEES"."JOB_ID" IS 'Current job of the employee; foreign key to job_id column of the
jobs table. A not null column.';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "HR"."EMPLOYEES"."SALARY" IS 'Monthly salary of the employee. Must be greater
than zero (enforced by constraint emp_salary_min)';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "HR"."EMPLOYEES"."COMMISSION_PCT" IS 'Commission percentage of the employee; Only employees in sales
department elgible for commission percentage';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "HR"."EMPLOYEES"."MANAGER_ID" IS 'Manager id of the employee; has same domain as manager_id in
departments table. Foreign key to employee_id column of employees table.
(useful for reflexive joins and CONNECT BY query)';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "HR"."EMPLOYEES"."DEPARTMENT_ID" IS 'Department id where employee works; foreign key to department_id
column of the departments table';
   COMMENT ON TABLE "HR"."EMPLOYEES"  IS 'employees table. Contains 107 rows. References with departments,
jobs, job_history tables. Contains a self reference.';
  CREATE INDEX "HR"."EMP_DEPARTMENT_IX" ON "HR"."EMPLOYEES" ("DEPARTMENT_ID") 
  ;
  CREATE INDEX "HR"."EMP_JOB_IX" ON "HR"."EMPLOYEES" ("JOB_ID") 
  ;
  CREATE INDEX "HR"."EMP_MANAGER_IX" ON "HR"."EMPLOYEES" ("MANAGER_ID") 
  ;
  CREATE INDEX "HR"."EMP_NAME_IX" ON "HR"."EMPLOYEES" ("LAST_NAME", "FIRST_NAME") 
  ;
  CREATE INDEX "HR"."EMP_NAME_UPPER" ON "HR"."EMPLOYEES" (UPPER("LAST_NAME")) 
  ;
  CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER "HR"."UPDATE_JOB_HISTORY" 
  AFTER UPDATE OF job_id, department_id ON employees
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  add_job_history(:old.employee_id, :old.hire_date, sysdate,
                  :old.job_id, :old.department_id);
END;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "HR"."UPDATE_JOB_HISTORY" DISABLE;
  CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER "HR"."SECURE_EMPLOYEES" 
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON employees
BEGIN
  secure_dml;
END secure_employees;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "HR"."SECURE_EMPLOYEES" DISABLE;
```

Comment: for Quick DDL, there is no option for including generating Foreign Keys, right? any plan to add it soon? it would be very useful. thanks

Comment: this does not solve the OP issue to export Foreign Key constraints

Comment: @Icaro how does it not?