# How to export an oracle table along with PK & FK constraints

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

i'm trying to export a table using sql developer, but in that case i can able to get only "pk" but not "fk", so how can i export along with "FK" constraints.
Is It possible are not..?

Comment: `dbms_metadata` will give you that

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there's no such option in SQL Developer.

Consider using appropriate utilities, i.e. [Data Pump](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_overview.htm#g1015896) or the [original export and import](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/exp_imp.htm#g1070082). True - those require some reading, but - at the end - you'll actually *know* what you are doing, instead of *clicking here & clicking there*, hoping for the best.

Hopefully, Jeff Smith (or someone else) will know how to do it in a tool you use. Jeff suggested the [DDL command in the Worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43358544/generate-ddl-with-oracle-sql-developer-to-include-foreign-keys), so - have a look, maybe you'll find it useful.